# yarn global add does not add binaries on Windows

Tags: yarnpkg

I am trying to add `node-sass` globally, using the command..

```
yarn global add node-sass
```

..but the binaries do not seem to get installed, although there are no error message and the command says that it added the package and installed its binaries successfully.

Adding other packages globally works just fine, (i.e `yarn global add gulp-cli`).

What is strange is that running `yarn global list` it shows me that node binaries are installed..

```
....
info "node-sass@4.5.3" has binaries:
   - node-sass
info "yarn@1.2.0" has binaries:
   - yarn
   - yarnpkg
Done in 3.39s.
```

.. but it doesn't exist in the global binaries directory (`yarn global bin`).

Answer (score 1):

Removing the package and adding it again worked for me.

```
yarn global remove node-sass
yarn global add node-sass
```

I tried installing `node-sass` globally using `yarn global add node-sass` previously, and it the installation failed due to missing `ms build-tools`. Maybe `yarn` somehow was still thinking that the package binaries were already installed and didn't try to reinstall them again.

Comment: Why did you post this question if you already knew the answer?!

Comment: @DaltonCézane I just resolved my issue by his answer. Every QA on SO has the potential to solve someone's problem. In case of yarn, it has some weird behaviors but i still prefer it over npm